# Assign textbox values to corresponding cells based on name

Tags: vba, loops, excel, textbox

I have a set of textboxes on a form, called sm1, sm2 etc, and I want to assign them to cells A1, A2, etc. Is there a way to put this in a loop, ie:

```
For i = 1 to 100
  Cells(i, 1).Value = ("sm" & c).Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure of VBA, but there should be "controls" collection on the form, you can access the elements of this by the control name, like you show above.

```
cells(i,1).Value = Controls("sm"&c).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method would be to use the `ControlSource` property of each textbox to bind them to the relevant cells

Answer (score 0):

With the textboxes on a form you can use the Controls collection.

```
For Each oControl In Me.Controls
    If Typename(oControl) = "TextBox" Then
        iCellNumber = Val(Mid$(oControl.Name, 3)) 'Assumes all textboxes have two letter names
        cells(iCellNumber ,1).Value = val(oControl.Text)
    End If
Next oControl
```

If the controls are on the sheet, you can use the shapes collection on that sheet

```
For Each oControl In Me.Shapes
    If InStr(oControl.Name, "TextBox") = 1 Then
        iCellNumber = Val(Mid$(oControl.Name, 3))
        cells(iCellNumber ,1).Value = val(oControl.Text)
    End If
Next oControl
```